# Filter unique field and push into array from an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js, function

I want the following solution, i tried with underscore, groupBy, but its returning a object of arrays with unique name inside an array, but i dont want that solution, i want something like shown below
How to convert this:

```
[
    {food: 'apple', type: 'fruit'},
    {food: 'potato', type: 'vegetable'},
    {food: 'apple', type: 'fruit'},
    {food: 'apple', type: 'fruit'},
    {food: 'potato', type: 'vegetable'},
]
```

into this:

```
[
    [ {food: 'apple', type: 'fruit'}, 
      {food: 'apple', type: 'fruit'}, 
      {food: 'apple', type: 'fruit'}]
    ],
    [ {food: 'potato', type: 'vegetable'}, 
      {food: 'potato', type: 'vegetable'}
    ]
]
```

using javascript or underscore, 
please help me do this with javascript function, thanks in advance

Comment: Where's your underscore code?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck in? What problem do you have?

Comment: Are you wanting to group by food or type, or both?

Comment: @Taplar either by food or type, anyone one of field, i want the output as mentioned above

Comment: const grouped = _.groupBy(this.state.messages, 'type');
                  console.log(grouped);        ---- it returns with name of unique value for each unique array of objects found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to get groups into a Map, then get the destructered values()

```js
const d = [
  {food: 'apple', type: 'fruit'},
  {food: 'potato', type: 'vegetable'},
  {food: 'apple', type: 'fruit'},
  {food: 'apple', type: 'fruit'},
  {food: 'potato', type: 'vegetable'},
];
const groupBy = 'food'; // change to whatever key you want to group by
const res = [...d.reduce((a,b) => a.set(b[groupBy], (a.get(b[groupBy]) || []).concat(b)), new Map).values()];
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.prototype.reduce` amd then map values

```js
const array = [
    {food: 'apple', type: 'fruit'},
    {food: 'potato', type: 'vegetable'},
    {food: 'apple', type: 'fruit'},
    {food: 'apple', type: 'fruit'},
    {food: 'potato', type: 'vegetable'},
];

let data = array.reduce((prev, curr) => {
  if (curr.food in prev) {
    prev[curr.food].push(curr);
  } else {
    prev[curr.food] = [curr];
  }
  return prev;
}, {});
data = Object.keys(data).map(key => data[key]);
console.log(data);
```

Comment: You can simply use Object.values() instead of the second map

Comment: @bambam Object.values() is not supported in IE that's why, however, good idea if polyfil is in place

Comment: :D https://www.xfive.co/blog/stop-supporting-ie10-ie9-ie8/, https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-stop-wasting-time-developing-for-internet-explorer/ :D